# How to solve OpenAI gym's 'Module has no attribute error'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter-lab, openai-gym

I follow the exact same folder structure for OpenAI Gym but still get attribute not found error upon using `gym.make()`. My folder structure is as below.

```
my_gym
  -->examples
      ---MAIN_ENV 
  -->my_rl_gym
        --->envs
               ---__init__
               ---main_env    #contains a class called Myxyz as registered below
        ---__init__

  -->setup.ipynb
```

The below is how I register in the `__init__` inside envs folder

```
from gym.envs.registration import register

register(
     id='XYZ-v0',
     entry_point='my_rl_gym.envs:Myxyz'
)
```

The below is in the `__init__` inside my_rl_gym folder i.e. outside envs

```
# from my_rl_gym.envs.main_env import Myxyz

#### THIS above line is actually correct BUT gives error as No module named 
#####'my_rl_gym.envs.main_env ' . Hence, I changed this to below line.

import main_env
```

The error comes upon calling the make command

```
env = gym.make('XYZ-v0', **env_args)
```

Traceback is:

```
----> 6 env = gym.make('XYZ-v0', **env_args)
      
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in make(id, **kwargs)
    674 # fmt: on
    675 def make(id: str, **kwargs) -> "Env":
--> 676     return registry.make(id, **kwargs)
    677 
    678 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in make(self, path, **kwargs)
    518         spec = self.spec(path)
    519         # Construct the environment
--> 520         return spec.make(**kwargs)
    521 
    522     def all(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in make(self, **kwargs)
    137             env = self.entry_point(**_kwargs)
    138         else:
--> 139             cls = load(self.entry_point)
    140             env = cls(**_kwargs)
    141 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gym\envs\registration.py in load(name)
     54     mod_name, attr_name = name.split(":")
     55     mod = importlib.import_module(mod_name)
---> 56     fn = getattr(mod, attr_name)
     57     return fn
     58 

AttributeError: module 'my_rl_gym.envs' has no attribute 'Myxyz'
```

What is the problem here? The folder directories are correct and the way of defining is also correct. For e.g. see https://github.com/MartinThoma/banana-gym
Is it because I need to have any setup file? because if so then I did and got the typeerror as in question [Getting Type error with setup file in OpenAI gym](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72073524/getting-type-error-with-setup-file-in-openai-gym)

Comment: I think you need to switch the contents of the two `__init__.py` files and also have the content of the inner one as `from my_rl_gym.envs.main_env import Myxyz`.

Comment: @Sharan Thanks for the reply. But are you sure switching is right? I did & it didn't do any difference and moreover, in every Gym example I saw they do the register() in the outer init file and it is what I did too and also given in the sample link attached.

Comment: @Sharan You are right about the import statement but as I said in question, that I don't why but it gives the no module found error. That's why I just wrote the simple import statement since they are all in the same folder anyway and the error goes away. BUT I know this is wrong since no other GYM example does like this. Maybe soln. to the question will also solve this automatically

Comment: Could you push your code to github? I can send in a PR with the appropriate changes required.

Comment: @Sharan Oh ok, I never done that and also don't think I would be comfortable putting the code out there. Because I am replicating some paper code (already in github) so that I understand it & then do changes acc to my application. So, I used a different notations in the ques. to avoid resemblances to original paper code since in actual it doesn't have any mistakes. I wanted to see want I am doing wrong. Isn't it possible for you to comment here and let me know? I will keep doing the changes as per your suggestions. It will be a practice to me too.